# Access Variable Outside Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

What am I missing here?  If I run a `print @sql` statement and run that statement directly in SSMS I get the value that I am after.  However, if I run the dynamic sql and try to access `Print @value1` outside the dynamic sql no value is returned.

How can I access the value of `@value1` from outside my dynamic sql?  In my syntax below, it always returns nothing, as if the value does not exist!

```
Declare @Name varchar(100), @value1 varchar(100), @sql nvarchar(max)
Set @Name = 'Jalen'
set @sql = 'Declare @value1 varchar(100) Select @value1 = id 
            from openquery(192.168.500.300,''Select id 
             from massmailer where empname in ('''''+@Name+N''''')'')'
Print @value1
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

I tried to modify my `Exec` statement to:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @retvalOUT=@value1 OUTPUT;
```

This gives me an error of:

> Msg 214, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
>   Procedure expects parameter '@parameters' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>*Community Wiki answer originally left as question comments*</sub>

You need:

```
EXEC sp_executesql
    @sql, 
    N'@value1 varchar(100) OUTPUT',
    @value1=@value1 OUTPUT;
```

An online demonstration of the technique: http://rextester.com/GDL49591

Answer (score 0):

Paul White's answer is correct, but I'd also add that in the original post, the @sql is not defined correctly. The correct script should be

```
Declare @Name varchar(100), @value1 varchar(100), @sql nvarchar(max)
Set @Name = 'Jalen'
set @sql = ' Select @value1 = id 
            from openquery(192.168.500.300,''Select id 
             from massmailer where empname in ('''''+@Name+N''''')'')'


EXEC sp_executesql
    @sql, 
    N'@value1 varchar(100) OUTPUT',
    @value1=@value1 OUTPUT;
print @value1;
```

i.e. notice inside @sql, there is no 'declare @value1 varchar(100)'. If you keep it there, you will have this error

> Msg 134, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>
> The variable name '@value1' has
>   already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query
>   batch or stored procedure.